# How to estimate time for zipping a deep and big directory?

Tags: time, zip

A static server directory for images.
number of subdirectory is about 4,000
number of files is about 2,000,000
total size of this directory near 200G.

```
 zip -r images.zip ./*
```

I want to know is how to estimate time when I want to zip this directory?

Answer (score 0):

Different OS have different applications, and there are many applications, who give some options to user on how to zip the file(Ex: Fast, compressed, ...). Try to look for it on your application.

Answer (score 0):

Note the option `-dd` to `zip`. Capture output from `zip` process and multiply each dot with the value of `-ds`. You will probably need to be okay with inter-process communication, `exec`, `fork` and pipes.

> ```
>    -dd
>    --display-dots
>           Display dots while each entry is zipped (except  on  ports  that
>           have  their  own progress indicator).  See -ds below for setting
>           dot size.  The default is a dot every 10 MB of input  file  pro-
>           cessed.   The -v option also displays dots (previously at a much
>           higher rate than this but now -v also defaults  to  10  MB)  and
>           this rate is also controlled by -ds.
> ```

Alternately you can just read the lines and counting how many files are added vs. how many exist; this is less precise given that sizes might differ wildly.

You could also just count files, but reference file sizes - this is easier than counting dots, has good accuracy, but you lose resolution (at least until you already process several files).

In any case, `quantity_processed_so_far / time_so_far * total_quantity` should give you a total time estimate.